Calculate the product of the segments described below
Points $A0, A1, A2.....A_{2n}$ divide a circle of radius whose size is $R$ into an odd number of congruent parts, $B$ is a point diametrically opposite to point $A0$. Calculate:
$BA1. BA2. BA3. BA4. ....BA_n$
(Ansewr:$R^n$)
$BA_1=BA_2$
$\sin 60^o=\frac{L}{2A_1B}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2} \implies\sqrt3A_1B=L$
$L=R\sqrt3\implies A_1B=R$
$\therefore BA_1.BA_2=R^2=R^n$
How to extrapolate to other polygons?


Since $A_0A_1=A_1A_2=A_2A_3= ... =A_{2n}A_0$
Let $\angle A_0BA_1=\angle A_1BA_2=\angle A_2BA_3=...=\angle A_{2n}BA_0=\theta$ ($\angle$' are subtended $=$ segments)
Polygon $A_0A_1A_2...A_{2n}$ has $2n+1$ sides then measure of an exterior $\angle=\frac{360^{\circ}}{2n+1}$
and an interior $\angle=180^{\circ} -\frac{360^{\circ}}{2n+1}=\frac{360^{\circ}n - 180^{\circ}}{2n+1}$
in $\triangle A_0BA_1$, $\angle A_0 = \frac{\angle A_{2n}A_0A_1}{2}=\frac{180^{\circ}n - 90^{\circ}}{2n+1}$, $\angle A_1=90^{\circ}$($\angle$ in semicircle) then $\theta=90^{\circ} - \frac{180^{\circ}n - 90^{\circ}}{2n+1} = \frac{180^{\circ}}{2n+1}$
Hence $(2n+1)\theta = 180^{\circ}$ and $\sin\theta = \sin2n\theta$

$\cos\theta = \frac{BA_1}{2R}$ (in $\triangle A_0BA_1$)
$\cos2\theta = \frac{BA_2}{2R}$ (in $\triangle A_0BA_2$)
$\cos3\theta = \frac{BA_3}{2R}$ (in $\triangle A_0BA_3$)
$............................$
$\cos n\theta = \frac{BA_n}{2R}$ (in $\triangle A_0BA_n$)
$$\cos\theta \times \cos2\theta \times \cos3\theta \times ... \times \cos n\theta = \frac{BA_1}{2R}\times\frac{BA_2}{2R}\times\frac{BA_3}{2R}\times ... \frac{BA_n}{2R}$$
$$\frac {2^n \times \sin\theta \times\cos\theta \times \cos2\theta \times \cos3\theta \times ... \times \cos n\theta}{2^n \times \sin\theta} = \frac{BA_1 \times BA_2 \times BA_3 \times ... \times BA_n}{2^n \times R^n}$$
$$\frac {\sin {2n}\theta}{\sin\theta} = \frac{BA_1 \times BA_2 \times BA_3 \times ... \times BA_n}{R^n}$$
$$BA_1 \times BA_2 \times BA_3 \times ... \times BA_n = R^n$$

Excellent..thanks
